# Property does not exist on type ts

Tags: typescript

I made a function that creates a username and adds the property in the object

```
// function to create usernames
const createUserNames = function (accs) {
  accs.forEach(function (acc) {
    acc.username = acc.owner.toLowerCase().split(' ').map(name => name[0]).join('');
  });
};
```

now when I'm trying to user that property in another function I'm getting

[image: please check this img]

I'm getting

> Property 'username' does not exist on type '{ owner: string; movements: number[]; interestRate: number; pin: number; }'.ts(2339)

When I print my object on the console the property it's there

Comment: You need to add `username` property to your type.

Comment: This sounds like an IDE warning, not a JavaScript error.

Comment: And the suffix `.ts` implies that this is TypeScript, not JavaScript.

Comment: so what should i do to fix this

Comment: Please copy in your code instead of using a screenshot. The screenshot is less accessible, cannot be copied, and cannot be searched.

Answer (score 2):

The error suggests that the type of the accounts is derived automatically. You could go to the source where the type is determined and expand it to include the property. e.g.

```
function getAccounts(): Account[] { // <- Explicit return type
  // ...
}

interface Account {
  owner: string;
  movements: number[];
  interestRate: number;
  pin: number;
  username?: string; // <- declares optional property
}

// ...

const accounts = getAccounts();
```

Or you could make the function that adds the property more functional in that it takes the accounts as argument and returns new instances with the new property added, so the original type does not need to change.

Something like this:

```
const createUserNames = function (accs: Account[]) {
  return accs.map(function (acc) {
    return {
        ...acc,
        username: acc.owner.toLowerCase()
            .split(' ').map(name => name[0])
            .join(''),
    };
  });
};

const accounts: Account[] = /* get accounts */;
const accountsWithNames = createUserNames(accounts);

interface Account {
  owner: string;
  movements: number[];
  interestRate: number;
  pin: number;
}
```

The type of `accountsWithNames` will then be:

```
const accountsWithNames: {
    username: string;
    owner: string;
    movements: number[];
    interestRate: number;
    pin: number;
}[]
```

There might be some other options as well.

(Also mind the casing, `userName` is not the same as `username`)

Comment: thanks you very much sir, i am beginner to programming so i didn't really get everything you said but i defined optional property username : 'string' on my account object and it worked.

Comment: Glad it helped at least. If this then sufficiently answered your question, you can click the check mark outline next to the question to accept it.